# Various way to stop a thread - which is the correct way

Tags: java, multithreading

I had came across different suggestion of stopping a thread. May I know, which is the correct way? Or it depends?

**Using Thread Variable** http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

```
private volatile Thread blinker;

public void stop() {
    blinker = null;
}

public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            thisThread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

---

**Using boolean flag**

```
private volatile boolean flag;

public void stop() {
    flag = false;
}

public void run() {
    while (flag) {
        try {
            thisThread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

---

**Using Thread Variable together with interrupt**

```
private volatile Thread blinker;

public void stop() {
    blinker.interrupt();
    blinker = null;
}

public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (!thisThread.isInterrupted() && blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            thisThread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't u use java concurrency package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of these is the "correct" way, they're all valid. Which one you use depends on your circumstances, and which one works best for you.

As long as you don't use `Thread.stop()`, and you tidy up any resources left open by your threads (connections, temp files, etc), then it doesn't really matter how you go about it.

Comment: While researching this question for myself, I found this reference explaining the problem with `Thread.stop()` and two possible alternate implementations. It seems that no matter what your language, using the equivalent of `Thread.stop()` is always a terrible idea: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/THI05-J.+Do+not+use+Thread.stop()+to+terminate+threads

Answer (score 2):

I always use the boolean flag - its the simplest.
Its really short and easy to understand for reviewers, but it has the handycap that you can't interrupt the sleep call. You should only use the interrupt variants for time-critical thread stopping. And, like skaffman said - Don't use `Thread.stop()`!

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
class Tester {
   public static void main() {
      Try t = new Try();
      Thread.sleep(10); //wait for 10 milliseconds
      t.interrupt(); // 'interrupt' i.e stop the thread
   }
}

public class Try extends Thread {
        @override
        public void interrupt() {
        //perform all cleanup code here
        this.stop();
        /*stop() is unsafe .but if we peform all cleanup code above it should be okay ???. since thread is calling stop itself?? */
    }
}
```